# Forcing User's Version of Excel When Creating .xslx file from Access 2007 VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

The Access 2007 app creates an Excel 2007 from a template file and saves as Excel 2007.

```
xlWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\TestFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=51 'Excel 2007 without macros
```

If Excel 2007 is installed, no problem. If both 2003 & 2007 are installed, the file is created as 2007, but the the computer is trying to create with 2003. A "Newer version..." error is given. Some of the formulas introduced in 2007 do not work (Name?). There is a Conversion process going on. Even if you open the file in 2007, the new formulas do not work.

Tried rebooting the computer and only openning Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be an issue with the order that the Excel versions were installed. The following commands will make Excel 2007 the default app:

In Excel 2007 - Office Button | Excel Options | Resources | Diagnose (run Microsoft Office Diagnostics) button.